# How to go into a numbered location within a remote server

Tags: ssh, terminal, scp

I have successfully logged in into a remote server using winSCP via SSH (using the host, port, username, and login).

Now within a terminal, I was directed by the administrator to transfer my files into a production machine numbered as 10.209.96.263

I am confused/ stuck at this part, how do I copy my files into this production machine within the remote terminal using winSCP. I tried doing `scp` command in terminal and was successful in carrying in out.

```
scp - P 44 ZINC000000626151_fix_.zip praveen@helloworld.loophole.in:~/

ssh praveen@10.209.96.263
```

**But, I am enquiring about a GUI based solution using either winSCP, Filezilla or pcman.**

Comment: Does this help? [WinSCP: Connection Tunneling](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/tunneling)

Comment: Yes its like what i wish. I read through the help and also followed the same. It is asking to make changes in the tunnel. But the tunnel is not taking argument in terms of number but rather as a file.

Comment: The tunnel should be configured with the *extenally accessible* host / port / username / login. Then you scp to the production machine using its numeric IP.

Comment: OK. That means the  movement to the  final destination is always via  scp and  not via direct folder  view

Comment: Really this is not the right place to ask about configuring a Windows SCP client

Comment: OK. Will note it

Comment: Consider asking at [su] instead. When re-posting there, please exmplain what you mean by *"But the tunnel is not taking argument in terms of number but rather as a file"*.

Comment: OK will do that